# how to cheack if email or password exist using openapi3 yml

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am new to using openapi 3. I use the code from the [link](https://editor.swagger.io/). I'm wondering if it's possible to check if I inserted a user with the same email?

Answer (score 0):

The link you referred is poining to the default swagger editor which contains pet store specification. If you have modified in that it must be in your local browser and does not reflect to others.

OpenApi is a specification so you can define apis which can check email id exists or not as shown below and you can generate server side code using the code generator, but the implementation has to be provided by you in the language you are working on such as java, python...

```
paths:
  /checkEmailId:
    get:
      summary: Check an email already exists
      operationId: checkEmailId
      tags:
        - email
      parameters:
        - name: emailId
          in: query
          description: emailId
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: If email does not exist
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                ....
```